# Display class constructor in PhpStorm on Ctrl + Space

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I create a new class instance I often could use the list arguments it accepts. Basically some class constructor prototype.

But I does not shows itself by default. Is there any option to display it aside from going into the class source code ?

Comment: You mean CTRL+P ?

Comment: Please clarify with some screenshot. But in general: 1) you can invoke `View | Quick Documentation` while using code completion popup 2) You can use `View | Parameter Info` once caret is inside `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

That was suggested by [Pete in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46014040/6331369), and that is what worked for me.